# Setting Text of UITextField while typing hangs then crashes application

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm creating some dynamic controls and am trying to hook up to the EditingChanged event so that I can append a percentage sign on some of the UITextFields as the user is typing...

The code is as follows

```
infoCaptureTextBox.EditingChanged += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    UITextField _thisTextBox = (UITextField)sender;
    string txtValue = _thisTextBox.Text.Replace("%", "");
    int numValue = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(txtValue, out numValue)) {
        if(infoCaptureField.InputType == "pc")
            _thisTextBox.Text = numValue.ToString() + "%";
    }
    else {
        infoCaptureTextBox.Text = "0";
    }
};
```

This works until you of course press a key at which point the application hangs for about 15-20 seconds and then crashes with nothing in the application output window.

Is setting the `Text` property of the `UITextField` the right way to go about is or is there another method/property I need to use?

I've tagged obj-c in case someone from that community has an idea of what the problem might be.

Thanks in advance peeps, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Changed the wrong tag from `c#` to `iPhone`

Comment: @robin - MonoTouch **IS** C# so I've put the tag back in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely causing a stack overflow by modifying the content in the EditingChanged method (causing it to reenter itself).

Try using the EditingEnded event instead, which is raised when the control resigns its first responder status.

If you need to do it as the user types, try using the ShouldChangeCharacters event instead.  Both of these are keyed off the UITextFieldDelegate, instead of using the central notification system and should resolve the issue.

Comment: I think you're right @Geoff - and your answer has pointed me to this excellent article http://escoz.com/editing-decimal-numbers-with-uitextfield-control-with-monotouch/ perhaps add it in your answer for future MonoTouch-ers :)

Comment: Thanks for the link to my blog. When I read the question title I thought of linking it here, great that it's been done already! :)